# Find some signal x[n] whose auto-correlation function is R[k]

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, filter-design, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation

I want to write a MATLAB code for generating a random message signal **[n]** where its autocorrelation function
is:
***R[k] = sinc^2 [1/4 k]*** where **k** is an integer. (Hint: Generate a process where autocorrelation is Dirac (i.e.,PSD has equal power on all frequency components, (you can use randn(1,N) where N is a large number,e.g., 100000)) and exploit Wiener-Khinchin Theorem.)

Is it possible to generate x[n] from its given autocorrelation function by applying these conditions?

If Yes,then how so?

Comment: You can generate *a* signal that has that autocorrelation function. But there are many such functions.

Comment: Kindly explain how can we generate it?

Comment: I can then apply a filter on it to extract one of those functions.

Comment: The title ".... original signal $x[n]$ ....." does not match what is asked for in the text of the question ".... find **a** random message signal  $x[n]$...."

Comment: @DilipSarwate I guess you are right,because original signal cannot be generated from the Autocorrelation function but any random signal having that auto-correlation function can be generated as okanerturk has suggested below. So, i'll modify the title of this question accordingly.

Comment: Your edited title still doesn't say what you want it to say: Find _some_ signal $x[n]$ whose autocorrelation function is the given function $R[k]$

Comment: There! I edited it now,thank you for clearing out the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the signal ofc!

First, I assume that you are familiar with some communication theory background and know what linear modulation is.

In order to obtain the desired auto-correlation, you need to use the proper pulse shaping function.
Let us assume that $x[n]$ is a complex-baseband linear modulated signal can be written as
$$x[n] = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_nh[k-nT] $$
where $a_n$ is the element of the symbol set (M-PSK, Q-PSK, points) satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|a_n|^2] = 1$, $T$ is the symbol period, and $h[n]$ is the pulse shaping filter impulse response. The power spectral density of $x[n]$ is proportional to

$$S_x[f] \propto|H[f]|^2$$
where $H[f]$ is the Fourier transform of the pulse-shaping filter. Without loss of generality, there is no harm in assuming that $H[f]$ is real for any $k$. Thus, the relation above can be written as $S_x[f] \propto H^2[f]$ as well. Knowing that the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of a (stationary) random process gives the power spectral density, we can deduce that

$$ R[k] \propto \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left\{ H^2[f] \right\} = h[k] * h[k]$$
where $*$ denotes the convolution.

**If you follow the steps below, you can generate the signal you desire:**

1. Take the Fourier transform of $R[k]$ to obtain $H^2[k]$. Take only the real values. Fourier transform will result in a real-valued $H^2[f]$ since the auto correlation function is an even function. Otherwise, some numerical precision issues may create problems.
2. Take the square root of $H^2[f]$ to obtain $H[f]$.
3. Take the inverse Fourier transform of $H[f]$ to obtain $h[k]$.
4. Generate the signal $x[k] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nh[k-nT]$. Please, be careful! $a_n$ must be zero mean.

That is it!

Comment: Thankyou so much @okanerturk for this detailed and to the point answer. I'll mark it correct right away. Just 1 question: what is the meaning of zero mean that you have mentioned that an should be?

Comment: And 1 more question: What will be T in the expression of x[k] since we do not know the time period of the random signal to be generated?

Comment: since $a_n$ seuences will be random, their mean should be zero.

Comment: T is the symbol period and can be selected any value as long as $a_n$ coefficients are generated independently. For now, there is no harm in accepting $T$ half of the length of h[k].